# Any way to launch application upon any push notification?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8

My scenario is that I get push notification from Azure or other source in my wp8 app. I know if user tap push it launch app. But in case user is away he may never notice something happened. I want to download some data form Azure as soon as app receive notification. Actually I doesn't need to depend on push notification only. I just need a solution that the app won't be polling all the time to download data from Azure. It can be anything that awake or launch the app. I need a power efficient application that receive data from Azure. Azure data is not available all the time. When data is available Azure will notify the app and app will start download data without user response automatically. I may sound too optimistic. Please just me some solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the best choice to make the data available later, even if the app doesn't immediately download it? If the app doesn't run, why would you download data for it -- that seems like a waste of battery and a data plan? (Why not just download it when the application is run)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said an app can not start automatically because of a push notification. But you may try this solution:

**you may create a scheduled task agent which will query the azure server if data is available, and if available**. Here you dont need to constantly poll the server, you just check in a interval. But still you'd have some limitation.